# php cron with get file content and insert data into database

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I created a spider and I want to run my spider in cron. It has following steps in the first step it get id from resume file. 2nd it get url from temp database. 3rd it put content title and meta tags to database. I included another file in my spider that fave following functions

1. Robot parser.
2. Checking robot meta tag.

It is not working with cron job.
`/usr/local/bin/php /home/user/public_html/cron.php`

Comment: can you define "not working"? Any errors? Have you checked your logs if there are any? And what is the exact syntax you used?

Comment: where from i can check error? simple cron is working text grabber is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run every minute:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/user/public_html/cron.php
```

You can see your cronjob logs in:

```
/var/log/syslog
```

Comment: my file not inserting data in to db its emailing me html code 1st 2 lines

Comment: [*"where from i can check error? simple cron is working text grabber is not working. – Hassan Mehmood"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41410041/php-cron-with-get-file-content-and-insert-data-into-database#comment70023246_41410041)

Comment: When you run a script in crontab all the path in your script have to be absolute. If you are including something in your Php file, check all path are set as absolute.

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you tell me how many cron can be run and how much the server load?